# Virtual machines to install for OS+Ubuntu+Windows

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization, unix, virtualbox

I have a MacBook Pro running OS X Lion 10.7.2, and I am going to install VMware to run virtual Windows.

I would like to use Ubuntu at the same time; is it technically possible? Do I need to install another virtual machine for that? In this case, which virtual machine is a best choice?

So ideally, I would like to use OS+Ubuntu+Windows, with a shared folder. Is it possible to adjust frequently the memory that a machine occupies?

PS: some info of my hardware:

**Processor:** 2.5GHz Intel Core i7
**Memory:** 8GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Comment: You do mean "virtual" machines in the title, right? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You don't need to install multiple virtualization software to run multiple virtualized systems.

You can use one virtualization software (VMware, Parallels or VirtualBox for example) to run multiple virtual machines at the same time.

You can edit the Virtual Machines.

[image: Virtual Machine settings]

You can change the amount of memory and the number of cores used by each virtual machine among other things, but it requires shutting down the VM you will edit.

[image: Memory and Processor settings]

For non Bootcamp virtual machines, you can also change the settings of virtual hard drives by creating new drives, removing existing ones or even resizing existing virtual hard drives (which are just files on your hard drive).

[image: Virtual Drive settings]

---

**Getting the best of both worlds**.

I would recommend you install Windows in Bootcamp first. Then back in Mac OS you create your Windows virtual machine from the bootcamp install. Follow [this procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/30371/vmware-fusion-running-windows-natively-from-a-bootcamp-partition-on-os-x/30376#30376).

This way you will be able to either launch Windows from Mac OS and run both systems at the same time and restart your computer to boot into Windows natively for better performance (for video games or power hungry applications).

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Someone will install for me VMware and Windows 7 (that I can't install myself because of the license) soon... Shall I reserve some place (or prevent something) for Ubuntu while installing Windows so as to add Ubuntu later?

Comment: @SoftTimur Just make sure there is enough room on your hard drive for ubuntu and the other systems you want to install. I usually install Windows using bootcamp (the apple dual boot). Then back to Mac OS I create the virtual machine with VMware Fusion which detects the Bootcamp install. Then I can use one Windows installation to either use Windows natively or from VMware. Beware, you will have to activate Windows twice. Once from Bootcamp and once from the virtual machine, even if you installed it once.

Comment: So if I understand well, I can't adjust the room of the folder VMware reserves afterward? I will have to fix some room for Windows and fix some room for Ubuntu within VMware in the very beginning?

Comment: Not really, if you use bootcamp the size of the partition you dedicate to windows will remain fixed. Otherwise you can decide to use virtual hard drives for your normal virtual machines which don't use pre-allocated files (default in VMware Fusion). You can set a maximum size (ex: 30GB) but the file containing the virtual hard drive will take only the space used on the virtual hard drive (ex: 2,1 GB). The file will grow as your virtual machine creates new files. It's the most convenient solution. You can add delete and change the size of virtual hard drives.

Comment: @SoftTimur I updated [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46142/11600) with more details concerning the setting you can edit for you virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I guess if I install virtual Ubuntu and Windows, they will be 2 `vmdk` files, under one  whole `Hard Disk (SCSI)`. Do you think a shared data folder among them and OS can be built?

Comment: Sharing data across virtual machines can be done through virtual shared folders (which require installing VMware tools on each virtual machine) or through network shared folders (each virtual machine can be configured to connect to a virtual network).

Comment: Sorry to insist... "through virtual shared folders (which require installing VMware tools on each virtual machine)" ==> Do you mean I need to install one VMware for Ubuntu and another VMware for Windows 7, or is it possible to build a virtual shared folder within one VMware for both Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Comment: @SoftTimur [WMware Tools](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html) is just a package with drivers and software which allows you to properly use the OS installed in the virtual machine. It allows seamless use of shared folders, of the mouse, of copy paste across Mac OS and the virtualized OS, better graphics support/performance, etc.